# IE7 & 8 jQuery Problems

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I have a jQuery script, that will not work in IE7 or IE8.  Interestingly, there are a few other jQuery scripts active on the page, and these all function, but the one below simply does not work.

I have created this [jsFiddle to demonstrate the functionality](http://jsfiddle.net/3WDf5/).  This works in IE9+, Chrome and Firefox.

This code updates textbox values based on certain criteria:

```
$(function () {
    $(".TAB1text1").change(function () {
        var $tr = $(this).parent().parent();
        var type = $tr.find("td:eq(1)").text();
        var scale = $tr.find("td:eq(6) input").val();
        if (type == " CERTAIN_TEXT_TOTAL " && (scale == 3 || scale == 3.0)) {
            $(".TAB1text1").not(this).val($(this).val());
        }
    });
});
```

Can anyone spot any functions / errors that would cause these scripts to stop functioning in IE7 and IE8?

Comment: I am assuming that one of the functions `.css()`, `.closest()` or `.find()` are not supported and causing the script to not work.

Comment: I have also removed all the extra jQuery scripts that are working, and the remaining two scripts above still do not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to work a solution to this problem.

First up, the `.trim()` did not work (so I edited my source code to remove the spaces:

```
$(function () {
    $(".TAB1text1").change(function () {
        var $tr = $(this).parent().parent();
        var type = $tr.find("td:eq(1)").text();
        var scale = $tr.find("td:eq(6) input").val();
        if (type == " CERTAIN_TEXT_TOTAL " && (scale == 3 || scale == 3.0)) {
            $(".TAB1text1").not(this).val($(this).val());
        }
    });
});
```

Next, I had to tweak the `<meta>` tag within the HTML `<head>` tag to include:

```
<meta content="IE=EmulateIE7">
```

I'm going to leave this here for future reference - I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#TAB1 td, #TAB2 td, #TAB3 td, #TAB4 td').each(function() {
      if ($.trim($(this).text()) == 'CERTAIN_TEXT') {
           $(this).closest('tr').css('background','#FFFF00');
       }
     });
    $(function() {
     $(".TAB1text1").change(function() {
         var $tr = $(this).parent().parent();
         var type = $tr.find("td:eq(1)").text();
         var scale = $tr.find("td:eq(6) input").val();
         if($.trim(type) == "CERTAIN_TEXT_TOTAL" && (scale == 3 || scale == 3.0)) {
            $(".TAB1text1").not(this).val($(this).val());
         }
     });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for this - but `.trim` is not supported in IE7.

Comment: its working fine...
$.trim() will work
you can check this fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/Shinov/3WDf5/2/

Comment: Strange it is not working for me in IE7 (using browser mode in IE10's developer tools).

Comment: just create a sample html page and check...
i have done a sample page and  its working properly in ie7 and 8